# Help me recognize this naval action

Tags: naval, battle, age-of-sail

I recall reading a Wikipedia article about an Age of Sail naval combat incident between two vessels, the smaller one being attacked by the larger one. I don't remember anything about the participants except that the defending vessel, despite being severely outmanned and outgunned, managed to win with little or no casualties on their side by somehow forcing the enemy below the deck and controlling the exits, allowing only one to come out at a time. Can anyone identify the naval action based on this description?

Comment: It's probably not too special. Most naval battles actually ended by the losing side's flight below decks - it was a sign of surrender.

Comment: @LubošMotl I think it was distinguished by the very good "KDR" scored by the defenders, who were outnumbered very vastly.

Comment: It doesn't fit your description exactly because, technically, the smaller ship attacked the larger one but it is a famous example of an unbalanced action - [HMS Speedy vs El Gamo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_of_6_May_1801).